# nginx redirect map folder

Tags: dictionary, nginx, redirect, subdirectory

I can't seem to get something to work to redirect anything from a folder or its subfolders to another folder in my nginx redirect map.

I want to redirect any request to anything within the folder /fauxnews to  /topics/faux-news. (Not to redirect to another file with the same name in the destination folder, but just to "/topics/faux-news", which will list all posts in that topic.)

I've found things that seemingly should work, like:

```
/fauxnews(.*)  /topics/faux-news/;
/fauxnews.*  /topics/faux-news/;
```

... but they aren't working. What should I use there?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found out you have to tell nginx you're using regex for a particular line, by inserting the tilde at the beginning. (The '^' is an anchor telling it to start the matching there):

```
~^/fauxnews(.*)  /topics/faux-news/;
```